# can't connect with pop3 server

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

i want to check my mails with an app. my code so far:

my provider uses SSL, see 
[here](https://hilfe-center.1und1.de/e-mail-c82645/1und1-e-mail-adresse-c84749/bedienung-c84680/einstellungen-fuer-ihr-e-mail-programm-a783411.html).

my code so far:

```
try {
            //1) get the session object
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.pop3s.host", "pop.1und1.de");
            properties.put("mail.pop3s.port", "995");
            Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

            //2) create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
            POP3Store emailStore = (POP3Store) emailSession.getStore("pop3s");
            emailStore.connect(<myMailAdress>, <password>);

            //3) create the folder object and open it
            Folder emailFolder = emailStore.getFolder("INBOX");
            emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

            //4) retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
            Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
            for(Message message:messages) {
                String from = message.getFrom()[0].toString().toLowerCase();
                Log.e("XXXXXX",from);
            }
            emailFolder.close(false);
            emailStore.close();

        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

the code runs until `emailStore.connect()`. There i get the Exception
`javax.mail.MessagingException: Connect failed; nested exception is:    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer`.

Comment: JavaMail knows the default port, you don't need to specify it.  Follow these [connection debugging tips](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).  Make sure the server doesn't require you to use SSL when connecting.  If it does, add the property `mail.pop3.ssl.enable` set to "true".

Comment: i edited my code and got a different error msg. See my edited post. I also included a link to my provider with the settings

Comment: You'll want to turn on [JavaMail session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug), although that probably won't give you enough information.  You might need to enable the java.net SSL debugging, as described in the links in the JavaMail [SSLNOTES.txt](http://javamail.java.net/docs/SSLNOTES.txt) file.